# Definition of a measure subspace

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The measure theory [notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes.pdf) (John K. Hunter) state:

**Definition 1.9** For set $X$ and $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on set X, a measure $\mu$ on the measurable space $(X, \mathcal{A})$ is a function such that:

- $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$
- It is countably additive. In other words, if $\lbrace A_{i} \in \mathcal{A} : i \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ is a countable disjoint collection of sets in $\mathcal{A}$, then

$$\mu \left ( \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_{i} \right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_{i})$$

**Definition 1.10**
If $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a measure space (a measurable space and a particular measure) and $E \subset X$ is a measurable subset, then the measurable subspace $(E, {\mathcal{A}|}_{E}, {\mu|}_{E})$ is defined by restricting $\mu$ to $E$ where:

- ${\mathcal{A}|}_{E} = \lbrace A \cap E : A \in \mathcal{A} \rbrace$
- ${\mu|}_{E}(A \cap E) = \mu(A \cap E)$

**My question**
From the answer in [Show that subspace measure is a measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585123/show-that-subspace-measure-is-a-measure), I get that the measure subspace is indeed a measure space, except that the answer seems not to mention that $E$ need to be a "measurable subset".

My interpretation of that "$E$ is a measurable subset of $X$" is that:

- $E$ is a subset of $X$
- there exists a collection of subsets of $E$ that forms a $\sigma$-algebra.

Why does $E$ really have to be a "measurable subset" of $X$ instead of just a subset of $X$?

Comment: what I understand by $E$ to be a measurable subset of a measurable space $X$ is just that $E\in\mathcal A$. Doesn't make sense to say that a set is measurable if we can define a $\sigma$-algebra on it, because we can do that every time, just choose the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset, E\}$

Comment: @Masacroso If $E \notin \mathcal{A}$ and $E \subset X$, then ${\mathcal{A}|}_{E} = \emptyset$. Then trivially, $\emptyset$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on ${\mathcal{A}|}_{E}$, and $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ is a measure on ${\mathcal{A}|}_{E}$. So $(E, {\mathcal{A}|}_{E}, {\mu|}_{E})$ still forms a measure space in this case.

Comment: "Why does E really have to be a "measurable subset" of X instead of just a subset of X?" Because it is defined like that, is just a definition. The reason to this choice of definition is that define an induced $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ is trivial.

Comment: After I read definition 1.5 again, I think your definition of a "measurable subset" is what the notes mean. Thanks.

Comment: We are talking about a restriction of measure  $\mu$. This means that its domain must be a subcollection of the domain of $\mu$ (which is $\mathcal A$) and it must give the same values to the sets in its domain as $\mu$. This demands that $E\in\mathcal A$ (which is the correct interpretation of "$E$ is a measurable subset").

Comment: @hamsteronwheels No, by the definitions above if $E\notin\mathcal A$ that does not  imply $\mathcal A|_E=\emptyset$;  the problem is that $\mathcal A|_E\not\subset\mathcal A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $E\notin\mathcal A$ then $E\cap A\notin\mathcal A$ for $A\in\mathcal  A$, so $\mu(E\cap A)$  is undefined.